# Replace normal state keymap in Evil with another

Tags: key-bindings, evil, dired

I don't like Evil collections or the Evil keybindings in the `dired-mode`. I would like to re-map only few keys in the normal state like `j`, `k`, and a few more keys with `g` prefix and I would like to keep the rest of the keys as in vanilla Emacs.

Is it possible to set all keys in the normal state to Emacs state in the `dired-mode`? Then I can just re-map a few keys with `evil-define-key`. I don't want to use Evil collections.

To clarify: I would like the normal state to have exactly the same keybidnings as the emacs state in the `dired-mode`, but then I will re-map some of the basic motion keys like j and k.

Comment: Please clarify a bit. What do you mean by "all keys in the normal state" and setting them "to Emacs state"?

Comment: Why not just use dired in emacs state?

Comment: That's exactly what I did initially. But, first it looks weird that I use j,k in emacs state, second, and most importantly when I switch to `wdired-mode` I jump into insert state, when I exit it and go back to `dired` I end up in normal state then I have to press `C-z` to get back to emacs state. Too much hustle. I think I will just use the evil-collections in the end, I suppose less hustle.